# elliptic curves with CM and hecke L-series

Tags: nt.number-theory, elliptic-curves

I know that if you have an elliptic curve E with complex multiplication, then the Hasse Weil L-series attached to it can be expressed in terms of Hecke L-series. Is there anything that can be said when the curve doesn't necessarily have CM or any reason why a similar fact would not hold?

On a related note, any basic facts/discussions of elliptic curves or Hecke L-series that you think is interesting or good to know would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, there are some theorems, but they are a little bit harder.  Look on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modularity_theorem